# How to solve ParameterMissing error using ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help me to solve the below error.

Error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in CustmersController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: users
```

When i am submitting the data,this error is coming.

My code is as follows

views/custmers/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Enter your data here</h1>
<center>
  <%= form_for @users,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
      <% if @users.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@users.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
              <% @users.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
      <% end %>
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <%= f.text_field :name,placeholder:"Enter your name",:class => "input-field" %>
  </p>
      <p>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <%= f.email_field :email,placeholder:"Enter your email",:class => "input-field" %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="phone">Phone no:</label>
        <%= f.telephone_field :phoneno,placeholder:"Enter your phone number",:class => "input-field" %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
      </p>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "BACK",custmers_index_path %>
</center>
```

controller/custmers_controller.rb

```
class CustmersController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def new
   @users=Custmer.new
  end
  def show

  end
  def create
    @users=Custmer.new(user_params)
    if @users.save
      flash[:notice]="You have signed up successpully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="You have not signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end
  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:users).permit(:name,:email,:phoneno)
  end
end
```

model/custmer.rb

```
class Custmer < ActiveRecord::Base
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  validates :name,presence:true,length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :phoneno, presence: true,length: {minimum: 10}

end
```

I am using rails version-4.2.0 and ruby version-1.9.3.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Yes,Its working @Arup .Thanks man.But i can say you the previous method was working also.I have succeeds many times before using that.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the stack trace accompanying your error, you could tell definitely where the problem is -- look for the first line in the stack trace that refers to your code (and not library code).

But a fair guess is the `require(:users)` line in your controller. It looks like you either copy/pasted this code from another controller, or changed the name of your controller after generating it as part of your scaffold.

It should be `requires(:custmer)` instead, as that is the class of the thing you're submitting.

As a general approach, you should follow the standard Rails practices for naming things, throughout. If you really want to use the misspelled, `Custmer` class, have at it, but use `@custmr` inside your controller and views to refer to an instance, not `@users`.

Comment: It should be `params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:phoneno)`